# Jquery remove() function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following piece of code:

```
$(".mydrop dt a").on('click', function() {
    if ($(".ulEvent").attr('style') === 'display: none;') {
          $('.rowSpaceEvent').remove();
        }
        $(".mydrop dd ul").slideToggle('fast');

        for (var i=0;i < $(".clsEvent").length;i++)
        {
            $(".eventDrop").append("<div class='row rowSpaceEvent'>&nbsp;</div>");
        }

    });
```

when running this code the first time the click event gets fired my divs are created as I expect them. If I go through the click event again and step the code it corrctly hits the remove() function, but does not remove the divs. Using chrome I can still see the elements. If I then go to the console window of chrome, then run the same line the divs are removed. Basically I'm building a custom dropdown on the fly with checkboxes and I need to push all the rest of the page down when I open the dropdown for the amount of items in the dropdown and then when the dropdown is clicked again it's closed and the rest of the page moves back.

Comment: Please put your HTML code or Jsfiddle link

Comment: Have you verified that the $('.rowSpaceEvent') matches anything at that point of time? You can do that by inserting a `console.log($('.rowSpaceEvent')); ` before line 3. If you open the developer console see if you can spot a log message. If so and if it is not an empty array, please let me know. If it is an empty array your selector seems to be wrong, if you see nothing the `$(".ulEvent").attr('style') === 'display: none;'` statement seems to return false

Comment: `$(".ulEvent").attr('style') === 'display: none;'` is a bad way to check CSS... You should be using `$(".ulEvent").css("display")`

Comment: try $(document).find('.rowSpaceEvent').remove();

Comment: @HanyAlsamman why....

Comment: @epascarello as i understood , remove does not working for him?

Comment: If I place the following code the remove will work when it looses focus. But I cant rely on the user always clicking away from the dropdown. They may just decide to close it.     `$(document).bind('click', function(e) {
            var $clicked = $(e.target);
            if (!$clicked.parents().hasClass(".mydrop")) { $(".mydrop dd ul").hide(); $('.rowSpaceEvent').remove(); }
        });`

Comment: @HanyAlsamman What you suggested makes no sense.

Comment: @HanyAlsamman Yes it does. I'm trying to emulate sliding the remainder page up in effect when the dropdown is closed

Comment: @bilpor ah sorry i got you wrong .